# Can Spring controller produce multiple content types combinations using same endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, controller, media-type

I need to serve multiple file types using same endpoint ( zip,pdf,xml).

I needed to add error handling to those endpoints so in case of error they should return json  (using controller advice) to indicate problem to user.
For example:

```
@GetMapping(value = "api/books", produces = {applicaton/zip, application/json}
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getZipedBooks(){...}
@GetMapping(value = "api/books", produces = {applicaton/pdf, application/json}
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPdfBooks()(...}
```

Without `application/json` Spring was able to differentiate between those endpoints and call correct one based on accept header. But when I added json Spring is now throwing exception:
`org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`
even if it can be deduced from `accept: application/json,application/pdf` header that getPdfBooks should be called.

Is there any way to configure spring to work with multiple content types on the same endpoint or I need to make special endpoints for every file type ?

Comment: If you are going to catch the exception in your controller advice, why you need to define additional produces value to your mainly target controller endpoint method? the controller advisor will handle it and return your desired JSON. 
So, no need to add to your main controller method.

Comment: Does it work with pdf,json vs json,pdf?

Answer (score 0):

I would reconsider this approach. If you want to return JSON on error do with [exception handling](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

So that you would add something like

```
private class ErrorResponse {
    String message;

    public ErrorResponse(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)  
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleException(Exception e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(new ErrorResponse(e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: It's not _impossible_, but this approach generally (using separate error handling) is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Unnecessary and old school. You just throw a ResponseStatusException from the controller method and Spring does the rest (no pun intended).

Comment: Did not know that. Thanks.